# Can you earn the "Everything we've been through" trophy on Survivor playthroughs?

Tags: the-last-of-us

On Survivor playthroughs, you cannot upgrade your listening distance with 
supplements, as the listening mechanic is absent.

Can you still earn the "Everything we've been through" trophy, which is for fully upgrading Joel's skills with the supplements, on a Survivor or Survivor+ playthrough?

Comment: also, on easy mode you have the "shiv master" upgrade automatically, so i assume the same question would apply there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by upgrading all of Joel's skills. Yes the listening mechanic is missing but because it isn't there you only need to upgrade all of the other skills.

Comment: So basically, that trophy is easiest to get on Survivor?

Comment: yes just about.

Comment: Other than, you know, playing on Survivor mode.